# Numpy shape incorrectly giving L in tuple?

Tags: python, numpy

Removed Python(x,y) and installed Mini-conda. Numpy version is 1.11.1.

```
A = np.array([1,1,1])

A
array([1, 1, 1])

A.dtype
dtype('int32')

A.shape
(3L,)


B = np.array([1.,1.,1.])

B
array([1., 1., 1.])

B.dtype
dtype('float64')

B.shape
(3L,)



C = np.array([1,1,1],dtype=long)

C
array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)

C.dtype
dtype('int64')

C.shape
(3L,)
```

I would expect only the last array to have (3L,) shape. The first two have always given me a shape of (3,).

Numpy documentation only shows examples without the L: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html

Anyone else seeing this, or did I break something??

NOTE: This is not a duplicate of questions asking what the L means. I'm trying to find out why it's suddenly saying that arrays of regular sized int and float have L in the shape. It seems like an error to me.

Comment: [Did you switch OSes or otherwise move to an environment where Python ints are 32-bit?](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5809)

Comment: @user2357112: My guess is that the change from Python(x, y) replaced a 32-bit build of Python with a 64-bit build of Python (both on 64-bit Windows). On a 32-bit Windows build, the 32-bit C `long` underlying a Python int matches the C `ssize_t` used for array sizes. On a 64-bit build, we get the mismatch between the 32-bit C `long` and the 64-bit `ssize_t`.