# Why does numpy.shape() sometimes not recognize higher dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, shapes

I realize this has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155977/numpy-shape-not-including-subarrays) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361944/numpy-shape-incorrectly-giving-l-in-tuple), but they are not the exact same problem, nor have any satisfying answer.

Let's say I have a list of lists of list of lists of floats.  (2x4x3x7 in this example)

But `np.shape` does not return the correct results.
Here's code that demonstrates the problem:

```
 m= np.array(m)
 print "shape:",m.shape
 # print "2:",m.shape[2] #error: tuple index out of bounds
 print m[0][0][0]
```

And the output is:

```
shape: (2L, 4L)
[  1.72237368e+06   2.89463050e+06   4.95241789e+06   7.93088857e+07   1.32649567e+08   2.25869653e+08   3.91489578e+08]
```

The point is, the `np.shape()` is giving the wrong result, saying there are only 2 dimensions when there are 4.

Does anyone have any clue why?

**Details:**

`m` is just one line of an even larger array.  I am doing image processing, and for each frame, I have different sets of statistics I am creating, each stored in this shape array.

So this `2x4x3x7` array is just one frame, one out of a thousand others.  The other 999 do *not* have this problem.  Their `shape()` works correctly.  There is nothing special about this frame that I can see.

The end goal is to pull out cross-sections based on certain parameters, and compare it to other images. 
for example:

```
m = np.array(m)
ms2 = m[:,1,:,5]
```

This gives an error
`could not broadcast input array from shape(2,4,3,7) into shape (2)`

Comment: Your input probably isn't 2x4x3x7. You've likely got an extra element or a missing element somewhere.

Comment: dude.  it's just an example.  did you even read the post?  Point is np.shape isn't working right, it's not even capturing the dimensions that obviously exist, since I was able to print them.  Don't -1 this, no one will help and I'll just have to ask it again

Comment: get rid of the -1, the question hasn't even been up 30 seconds

Comment: Post this again and you'll just get downvoted again, and dupe-closed. Whatever grid structure you think your real input has, it probably doesn't actually have that structure. Of course, you haven't posted a [mcve], so we can't actually debug your problem, hence the downvote.

Comment: The *point* is, np.shape isn't even detecting the correct dimensions.  The shape doesn't matter, jeez.

Comment: And a complete example requires the files I use.  I can't reduce an image to a minimal example.

Comment: hello. how do you create the m variable? can you add the full code and some data ? e.g. the specific frame that causes the error ?

Comment: You're probably nesting array *objects* within other arrays, and the question at 43155977 is probably the exact same issue. See the diagnostics by Dawid, plus look at `m.dtype`, if it shows `object`, that's even more evidence it's a dupe. If it's `float` or `int`, that's useful information.

Comment: @johnktejik the **point** is that, as others have pointed out, your error is in thinking that whatever list of list of lists you have that it is correctly whatever shape you think. Note, `numpy.ndarray` objects are *true multidimensional arrays*, that is, they are not "staggered" arrays, and every element has to conform to the shape. so if you did `np.array([[1,2], [3,4,5]])` that will return a *one dimensional array* with two elements, i.e. `shape == (2,)` wheras you might *think* it should be (2,2) or (2,3). The dtype=object will be a big give-away.

Comment: So barring you providing a [mcve], that is the only reasonable guess that one could come up with. It is a common error that has bitten numpy users before, and I am more willing to bet that *you* are mistaken about the nature of your list-object, rather than `numpy` is mistaken.

Comment: Print `[len(x) for x in m.flat]`, that is, the len of all elements of `m`.  The elements of `m` are probably lists.  The fact that `m` is 2d, means that it's the 3rd level of nesting that is ragged.  `np.array` has constructed an 'as-high-a-dimension` array as the lists allow, It would have constructed a 3d (or 4d) array if that third level had consistent lengths.

Comment: people who have a problem with this should look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155977/numpy-shape-not-including-subarrays

same question, no answers.  *it* didn't get downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

```
print(type(m))
print(type(m[0,0]) 
print(m[0,0,0])
```

My guess is that you have (2,4) `numpy array` that holds objects that can be considered `2D`, but `numpy` rightfully doesn't know about it.

Comment: Thank you for contributing something constructive.  Can you elaborate as to why numpy might not 'know' about said objects?

Comment: @johnktejik basically, numpy doesn't pretend to be smart. It knows what to do in case of lists, tuples and other numpy.ndarrays, but in other cases it will just try to make an array of objects that you passed to it. It's your responsibility to convert it into known format. Take a numpy/core/records.py: "def array", as an example.